# Sideways header

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to solve a sideways header problem. I intend on creating a globally sideways header like so on a website: [sideways header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AUqX.png)

However, my problem arises trying to separate the type (it's also breaking on 2 lines). I can't seem to make the vertical line contained or centered within the rectangle . When I resize my browser window it does not stay contained within the rectangle box. I would GREATLY appreciate any suggestions and advice!

What I have so far:

```css
.box {
  height: 1326px;
  width: 112px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f9f0e4;
}

.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Internet Explorer */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

.top {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Internet Explorer */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

.vl {
  border-left: 1px solid #f9f0e4;
  height: 620px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="bottom">CREATIVE STUDIO</p>
    <div class="vl">
      <p class="top">FLORENCE &mdash; ITALY</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the bigger questions you should ask yourself are

- are all clients going to have the screen size to allow this? (will this work on mobile, tablet and desktop alike?)
- are you alienating your customer in choosing this design?

Comment: According to the regarded screen shot, I think that it may go like vertical navigation bar with fixed height in `vh` unit of the container and  vertical overflow for the contents

Answer (score 0):

You can instead consider rotation on the whole box and use `vh` unit so the width is relative to height since it's getting rotated :

```css
.box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}

.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.top {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="bottom">CREATIVE STUDIO</p>
  <p class="top">FLORENCE &mdash; ITALY</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a horizontal line that should be in between I think from the OP's ss? and when resizing the container just shrinks as well.

Comment: @Highdef yes it shrinkg but kept in one line ... i think this is the op issue ... and yes i ommited the line (and some CSS) to focus on the rotation behavior

Comment: I'd say that using 100vh on width instead of 80% would be the ideal case for this?

Comment: I guess font would need to be made responsive too ;)